# NodeJS AWS Lambda Require not able to import subfolders

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

So I am attempting to deploy a zipped nodejs project to AWS Lambda to run the script for me. It has a directory structure similar to the following:

```
apps
  -api1
    -case1
      -index.js
    -case2
  -api2
    -case1
index.js
```

And you get the rest. The lambda can successfully find and run the index.js script, the problem is I import those api modules through a `require('./api1/case1);`. For some reason, the lambda is unable to find them and when I try to test it throws this error:

```
"errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module './apps/api1/case1'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
```

I've opened the zip I've uploaded and seen that the apps folder and everything in it is there in the correct spot, including the index.js file. Does anyone have any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue where I was zipping the entire folder which contains **app** folder and **index.js** file.

So after uploading, it was unable to locate.

instead, I selected all folders manually and compressed it. (I'm not compressing the root folder, I'm inside root folder and selecting all the required files and zipping it. ) and then uploaded.
Boom!!! it worked.

Comment: Sadly this is not the issue, I am packaging it all individually through `Compress-Archive -LiteralPath apps, config, node_modules, test, index.js, package.json -DestinationPath LambdaTest.zip`. And as stated in the question I've looked into the zip file and it contains all the files needed. It can find the index file fine, just nothing the index imports